# How to unquote CSV column with JSON text in drill query

Tags: apache-drill

My CSV text file has column data of the kind . It is JSON with the quotes escaped.

```
{\"code\":\"SOURCE\",\"display\":\"NPPES\"}]}
```

I am not able to query this column in drill as JSON using dot notation. Is there a JSON_UNQUOTE() function in apache-drill that will solve this problem?

```
apache drill (dfs.tmp)> select hl7s.hl7_bundle.code from hl7s limit 1;
+--------+
| EXPR$0 |
+--------+
| null   |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert this column as JSON, consider using `convert_fromJSON` function:

`select convert_fromJSON('{"num": 55, "nan": NaN, "inf": -Infinity}');`

https://drill.apache.org/docs/data-type-conversion/#convert_to-and-convert_from